# On maximum principle of spectral fractional Laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose $(-\Delta)^s u=g \geq 0$ in $\Omega$ and $u=0$ in $ \partial \Omega.$ Also suppose $u$ is $C^{2}$ non-negative and $(-\Delta)^s u=0$ in $\Omega \setminus B$ and $u\leq a$ on $\partial B $ where $B\subset \Omega$ is a unit ball and $a$ is a positive constant. Is it true that $u\leq a$ in $\Omega \setminus B$ where $s\in (0,1)$ and $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain.